# Complicated SQL View scenario

Tags: sql, view

I have a DB like this:

[image]

I would like to create a view that creates an ROI for each 'club'.
so ROI would be `(amountbet / amountwon) * 100`

Club 2's are ID's 1 and 3
`((5 + 10) / (10 + 20)) * 100`

and Club 1 is just id 2 which is tricky cause it will be a divide by 0 which is never good
`2/0*100`

So it should end up with 2 rows

```
club   |   ROI
2      |   200%
1      |   0%
```

I only just found out Views was a thing and have no idea how to tackle this (or if it's even possible)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation. I would rather return `NULL` for roi when nothing has been won:

```
select club,
       sum(amountbet) * 100.0 / nullif(sum(amountwon), 0) as roi
from t
group by club;
```

If you want `0` you can use `coalesce()`:

```
select club,
       coalesce(sum(amountbet) * 100.0 / nullif(sum(amountwon), 0), 0) as roi
from t
group by club;
```

Comment: Wow, perfect. It actually helps me understand views better as well. Thanks!

Comment: I can't seem to get INNER JOIN of the clubDetails table to associate with the returned id. Any thoughts?

Comment: @ThomasByy . . . Your question has no mention of a `clubDetails` table.  Perhaps you should ask a new question.